# How to write a function which returns complex in C++?

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to do numerical calculations with C++. Here is the sample code

```
#include <complex> 
using namespace std;


complex<double> complexDo(float a, float b){

    return (a+b,a-b);
}

int main(){

    cout << "complexDo="<<complexDo(3,2) <<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The terminal will show after compiling

```
complexDo=(1,0)
```

But I expect to appear like `(5, 1)`, and what is the problem here? Or this way of writing is not valid in C++?

Comment: You might want to turn on more compiler warnings. G++ can warn you about this: "warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `(a+b,a-b)` is equivalent to `(a-b)` because it's just a parenthesized use of the common [comma expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

To create an object you must use curly-braces `{}` as in

```
return {a+b,a-b};
```